# data can not be shown in the swift class inherited from UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a swift class

```
public class SwiftViewController : UITableViewController {

    public var _dataItems : [String]?;

    public var _cellStyle : UITableViewCellStyle?;

    public init(dataItems aDataItems:[String], cellStyle aCellStyle:UITableViewCellStyle)

    {
        super.init(style:UITableViewStyle.Plain);

        self._dataItems = aDataItems;

        self._cellStyle = aCellStyle; 
    }



    public override init(style aStyle: UITableViewStyle) {

        super.init(style: aStyle);

    }



    public override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil);

    }


    public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder);


        _dataItems = [];

        self._cellStyle = UITableViewCellStyle.Default;

    }



    public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        var c = self._dataItems!.count;

        return c;
    }



    public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

    {

        let rowId = "cellId";

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(rowId) as UITableViewCell?;

        if (cell == nil)

        {

            cell = UITableViewCell(style: self._cellStyle!, reuseIdentifier: rowId)

        }


        var item = _dataItems![indexPath.row];

        cell?.textLabel.text = item;

        return cell!;

    }

}
```

when I add it into an other viewcontroller

```
var ctrl3 = SwiftViewController(dataItems: ["Item1","Item2"],cellStyle: UITableViewCellStyle.Default);

        self.view.addSubview(ctrl3.view);

        if ctrl3.tableView != nil {

            ctrl3.tableView.reloadData();

        }
```

the tableview show nothing.

I debug the viewcontroller, the method

```
public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

is called correctly, and the return value is 2, but the method

```
public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

is never called.

My xcode is in version 6.1.

Anyone can help me find the issue of my code, thanks very much.

Comment: If `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is called and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not called it's usually because you return 0 in the former method.

Comment: the return value of tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: is 2

Comment: instead of adding the view as a subview present the view controller, i.e., change `self.view.addSubview(ctrl3.view);` by `presentViewController(ctrl3, animated: true)`

Comment: the problem is not self.view.addSubview(ctrl3.view) and i won't use self.presentViewController here

Comment: ctrl3 is a local variable, released automatically...